# c# ajax updatepanel only firing clientside event in .net masterpages

Tags: c#, ajax

I get this error when I click on the href link:  Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property 'walkRedCarpet' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

To me, this means it is not firing the OnClientClick event and treating the OnClick like a clientside event.. am I wrong?

The link (a href) is programmatically generated from the codebehind PageLoad event and is the contents of a placeholder.

CODE

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyFile.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.MyFile" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void walkRedCarpet(int eventID)
     {

     }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Call() {
         return Page_ClientValidate();
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPnlRedCarpet" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

PLACEHOLDER CONTENTS CODEBEHIND

```
<a href='#' OnClick='walkRedCarpet(" + eventID + ");' OnClientClick='return Call()' runat='server' id='linkEventShowImageSet'><img Width='125' Height='95'src='Images/" + strEventThumb.ToString() + "' border='0'></a>
```

PLACEHOLDER CONTENTS POSTCOMPILE

```
<a href='#' OnClick='walkRedCarpet(1);' OnClientClick='return Call()' runat='server' id='linkEventShowImageSet'><img Width='125' Height='95'src='Images/event-1-ready.jpg' border='0'></a>
```

I am very new to AJAX. I have scoured the webbernet and looked at countless examples until my brain is very soft and mushy. Please be gentle.

Comment: So..is it possible that the contents of placeholder once rendered are not runat='server' elements?  Meaning, the anchor tag is not running serverside.

Comment: How are you generating the code from the onLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to actually use a LinkButton and this:

```
        UpdatePanel1.UpdateMode = System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

to get it to work properly.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm half asleep, my first read made me skip the "runat="server"" you have in there. You are right as to the behavior, so what does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: They are all properly tagged with runat="server" as far as I can tell.

Comment: PLACEHOLDER CONTENTS POSTCOMPILE is the generated html.